# Lego EV3 Bluetooth connected with DX-BT12 weirdly

Tags: bluetooth, lego-mindstorms

I am working on Arduino demo application, try to connect Lego EV3 main brain brick to a dual-mode bluetooth [BT12](https://www.google.com/search?q=DX-BT12&oq=DX-BT12&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39.3455j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

On EV3 brick, the operations (searching and pairing) are going well, but after I click "connect", it shows "connected" and my bluetooth module is keeping flashing its red LED light, which means not connected well.

I tried to use another bluetooth module HC-05 which is a bluetooth 2.0 module. The code is working fine.

I am not sure if it's because of the dual modes of bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

The default channel for `DX-BT12` is `3`, not `1` which has been set in `RN-42` or `HC-06`. You can get access to `BT12` by typing :

```
sudo rfcomm bind 0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 3
```

and

```
cat /dev/rfcomm0
```